# time в чем хранить?

Tags: android, jodatime

Хочу сделать фрагмент, который будет получать время в long и отдавать время.
Время возвращаю в int.
Как его можно конвертировать в joda-time?
Мне нужно работать именно только со временем, без даты.
Необходимы операции сравнения и т.д.
Либо предложите другие варианты

```
val minutes = data.getIntExtra("minutes", 0)
val hours = data.getIntExtra("hours", 0)
startTimeLessons = DateTime(0, 0 ,0, hours, minutes)
```

Просто их потом в базе данных хранить, а там только примитивы

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать.

Если данные у вас приходят в long (в миллесекундах от 1970г.):

```
val datetime = DateTime(timeInMillis)
```

Если данные у вас приходят в ISO:

```
val dateTime = DateTime().parse(timeInIso)
```

Если у вас только часы и минуты, и вы будете игнорить дату в любой точке применения:

```
val dateTime = DateTime().now().withTime(hours, minuts, 0, 0)
```

Получение времени:

```
val hours = dateTime.hours
val minuts = dateTime.minuts
```

Хотя для пред последней задачи вам лучше изучить [Period, Interval и Duration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2653655/7609373).

Comment: спасибо использовал так startTimeLessons = DateTime().withTime(hours, minutes, 0, 0).

Только как такое время хранить в базе данных? joda-time. Конвертировать в long? а потом обратно доставать?

Comment: Как по мне это самый лучший вариант. Можно конечно в ISO ```2018-05-08T10:41:52Z```, но как по мне он хоть и понятнее для человека, но с ним нужно провести больше манипуляций, что может быть медленее. Плюс в том что такой формат может хранить таймзону: 2018-05-08T10:41:52+03:00 или (+0300). А так вам прийдётся хранить её отдельно. WARNING: в некоторых случаях joda time, сам прикрепляет местную тайм зону. Потому, будьте аккуратны, проверяйте поведение.